# Register broadcast receiver dynamically does not work - BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

Using `Log` class to track Runtime show that `onReceive()` methode does not called,why ?

**Register broadcast receiver dynamically**

```
 private void discoverDevices () {
    Log.e("MOHAB","BEFORE ON RECEIVE");

     mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("MOHAB","ON RECEIVE");
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                Bluetooth b = new Bluetooth(device.getName(),device.getAddress());
                list.add(b);
            }
        }
    };
    Log.e("MOHAB","create intentFilter");
    // Register the BroadcastReceiver
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy

}
```

Comment: Why is your broadcast reciver initialized in a function?

Comment: this code to discover nearby bluetooth devices ..  i put this code in onClick() event  what is the right way  ?

Comment: BroadcastReceiver are called when ecountered by broadcasted message. initialize it outside onCreate method and not in your function.

Comment: i need Broadcast start if button clicked .

Comment: you mean your receiver. then you register `registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);` inside button click. not initializing of `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: should i register receiver in onCreate() event ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90044/discussion-between-error-and-jolson).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90048/discussion-between-error-and-jolson).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you missed is that you need to start a device discovery

First, get the bluetooth adapter

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

After that, you start the discovery by calling

```
mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

You should read the details here as well, e.g. about `cancelDiscovery()`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startDiscovery%28%29

**P.S.** Also, it is suggested to use `context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE)` to get the BluetoothAdapter on API 18+, according to official doc.

> To get a BluetoothAdapter representing the local Bluetooth adapter,
> when running on JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and below, call the static
> getDefaultAdapter() method; when running on JELLY_BEAN_MR2 and higher,
> retrieve it through getSystemService(Class) with BLUETOOTH_SERVICE.

**Edit:**
Be reminded that you need [BLUETOOTH_ADMIN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) permission to `startDiscovery()`

Comment: i missed start Discovery() but there is another bug with Receiver !

Answer (score 43):

Apart from the fact that [starting with Android 6.0 you have to have the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission to receive `ACTION_FOUND`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_FOUND) (as @siniux already mentioned), there's another related thing:

`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` is among [dangerous permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#perm-groups) that you have to explicitly request from user at run time (another security improvement that came in 6.0).

To diagnose, you can run `adb logcat | grep BroadcastQueue`, and see something like this:

```
W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { 
    act=android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND flg=0x10 (has extras) } 
    to ProcessRecord{9007:com.examplepackage} (pid=9007, uid=10492) 
    requires android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION due to sender
    com.android.bluetooth (uid 1002)
```

So, the **correct procedure for BT device discovery on Marshmallow** is as follows:

1. Have `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission requirement in manifest along with usual bluetooth permissions:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   ```
2. [Ensure you have run-time permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-check) for `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`

   ```
   protected void checkLocationPermission() {
       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
               != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                   new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                   REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                      String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
       switch (requestCode) {
       case REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
           if (grantResults.length > 0
                   && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               proceedDiscovery(); // --->
           } else {
               //TODO re-request
           }
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

   }
3. Register a broadcast receiver for `ACTION_FOUND` and call `BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()`

   ```
   protected void proceedDiscovery() {
       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
       filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_NAME_CHANGED);
       registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

       mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
   }
   ```

**Funny thing about `ACTION_NAME_CHANGED`**. Although 6.0 won't deliver you `ACTION_FOUND` without the permission for coarse location, you'll still get `ACTION_NAME_CHANGED` events, which are usually teamed up with `ACTION_FOUND` when devices are discovered. I.e. you get both events, so without the permission, you can still handle `ACTION_NAME_CHANGED` for pretty much the same behavior. (Gurus, correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Correct thing ^^ Thanks. I think Google's doing bad things now on Android :D

Comment: That anwser brings so much usefull informations. Thank you

Comment: Yes, unfortunately after 3 hours, it was the coarse permission to find the devices.... (although I didn't see it in the monitor logs)

Answer (score 13):

I was having a similar problem with a Broadcast Receiver.
Then I found this:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id

Basically, on 6.0 you must use the location permission to scan for Bluetooth devices.

Answer (score 6):

As replied by experts, you may please check the following points to get ACTION_FOUND work in Android 6 and above,
1. In addition to setting permissions of BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, try

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Sometimes these two may not be needed, but it worked for me. Also you have to seek user permissions dynamically using the codes

```
int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 200;
int permissions=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission (this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
```

Now write your codes for performing the required operation. I have added one startDiscovery() method just after this.
Surely, this will work for you...
Happy coding...

Comment: It worked for me. I have missed the Runtime permission part.

Answer (score 4):

i dont know if your code is correct in getting bluetooth device. here is what i feel about your code is. intialising and registering BroadcastReceiver inside a function is a bad idea. you should do it outside `onCreate()` method.
here's the thing you need to do in your code

as about registering Reciver that has to be done in `onCreate()` like this

```
registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
```

following with initializing or reciever

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("MOHAB","ON RECEIVE");
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                Bluetooth b = new Bluetooth(device.getName(),device.getAddress());
                list.add(b);
            }
        }
    };
```

unregister reciver in `onPause()` do not forget that

and in your `discoverDevices()` just return the `list` of devices added by reciver for every call of that fumction;

Comment: public void regigsterReceiver () {
      
       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
       registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);  }  How i register receiver

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a answer, as I cant comment with my current Rep level.

Do you have the Bluetooth permisson include in you AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

If not, try(and research) each one separately as I don't recall the importance of each one.

If you do have these, please include more of you code, so it will be possible to diagnose your issue.

Comment: the problem not with bluetooth code and  i am using those permissions . issue is the onReceive does not called

Answer (score 0):

I found that the device I was developing on (Galaxy S4) needed to be restarted before the broadcasts continued to be received.

However, in my case I had been receiving them without issue until they (randomly?) stopped being received and no matter what I did (close app, reinstall app) the broadcasts weren't being received.

Comment: You forgot to unregister receiver in onDestroy?