# BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND Not Working in Android Devices with Version Marshmallow

Tags: android, bluetooth, redmi-device

This following is My Code to Detect Bluetooth Related Operations.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.i(TAG, "-------------------Bluetooth Operation-----------------:");
        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            if (state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {
                Log.i(TAG, "-------------------BlueTooth ON-----------------");
            }else if(state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF){
                Log.i(TAG, "-------------------BlueTooth OFF-----------------");

            }
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "-------------------BlueTooth Discover Started-----------------");
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "-------------------BlueTooth Discover Finished-----------------");

        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Log.i(TAG, "-------------------New Device Found-----------------");
            Log.i(TAG, "-------------------------NAME        :" + device.getName());
            Log.i(TAG, "-------------------------MAC ADDRESS :" + device.getAddress());
        }
    }
};
```

It Works Fine with Most of the Android Devices.But the Problem is Only with Android Devices with Marshmallow .They Doesn't Return **BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND** when a new Device was Found.I have properly registered the Broadcast Receiver as Mentioned in the [Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#DiscoveringDevices)

Any Solutions...?

Comment: Sry for the Duplicate Question i have Found the Result from this [StackOverflow Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33052902/5740760)

Comment: Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188887/android-6-0-bluetooth-no-code-exists-for-action-found-broadcast-intent