# Get rssi value with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, rssi

I want to get rssi value with BroadcastReceiver. When I implemented the code below on Android 4 worked well(also the code just had the BroadcastReceiver and was registered the broadcastReceiver and didn't have that requests for permissions) but didn't answer in Android 6 and upper. I read that BroadcastReceiver has changed for Android 6+ and it needs ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission.I added this in android manifest and requested permissions in MainActivity but when I run the code on phone which has Android 7 and click the button when a bluetooth device is near that, is throws exception and when nothing is near when I click the button it shows nothing.
Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BluetoothAdapter BTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
        checkLocationPermission();
        proceedDiscovery();
        }
        });
        }



private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String action = intent.getAction();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,action, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                int rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
                String name = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME);
                TextView rssi_msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                rssi_msg.setText(rssi_msg.getText() + name + " => " + rssi + "dBm"+"\n");
            }
        }
    };

protected void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 0);
                int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 200;
                int permissions=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission (this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }}
    }
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 0: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    proceedDiscovery();
                } 
else{}
                break;
            }
        }}
    protected void proceedDiscovery() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_NAME_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        BTAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }}
```

and my android manifest has these permissions:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

I got help for permissions from this link:
[correct procedure for BT device discovery on Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37482277)

Exceptions in logcat:

```
08-16 14:33:16.341 6630-6630/com.example.hanane.rssi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hanane.rssi, PID: 6630
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND flg=0x10 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } bqHint=1 (has extras) } in com.example.hanane.rssi.MainActivity$2@a1e9394
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1565)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1453)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xffffffd4
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1184)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:460)
        at com.example.hanane.rssi.MainActivity$2.onReceive(MainActivity.java:75)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1185)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1565) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1453)
```

Comment: `is throws exception` which?

Comment: that is obvious thing, but what exception does it throw? where is the stacktrace of that exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: it was too long for comment I added exception to my question @VladyslavMatviienko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your exception says, the problem is in calling

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,action, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

As documentation says, `Toast.makeText` requires string resource identifier (`R.string.<something>`) as 2nd parameter in one overload, or a `String` in another, while you are passing `action`, which is causing Toast to look for the resource with the identifier of the `action` value, which it can't find.

If you want to `Toast` the `action` value, you have to convert it to string first. Easiest way is to use it as `action + ""`:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,action + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I did this but it throws exception again.

Comment: @hananeYousefi which exception now?

Comment: The same as before. I also commented the Toast but it throw exception again @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: @hananeYousefi it can't throw exception about toast if you commented it. Check that you have build the app from the up to date code

Comment: I deleted all Toasts and it worked well thank you for your help ;) @VladyslavMatviienco